# Unicode HOT BEVERAGE (U+2615) in Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, unicode

In the screenshot below, I am looking at an email with a unicode HOT BEVERAGE (U+2615) character.  The character is displayed correctly in the OSX dialog and in the developer tools, but not in the web page.  Why is Chrome ignorant of this character and how can I cause it to be displayed correctly?

- Chrome Version: 25.0.1364.99
- OSX: 10.8.2

[image: Email with HOT BEVERAGE]

Comment: Duplicate? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/why-do-emoji-like-appear-when-i-use-safari-but-not-chrome

Comment: Note that the particular glyph you show here is from the Apple Color Emoji font, which has special characteristics and is only supported by Apple apps (and not even all of them, e.g. Pages does not show it).

Comment: Chrome should always display it regardless.  Must be a bug they need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%98%95%20-%20Unicode%20Character%20%27HOT%20BEVERAGE%27%20%28U%2B2615%29) shows what fonts support this character.

So you can use a CSS/style rule to select a font that supports the character. I notice that it's not a glyph in Arial Unicode MS, so I'm not sure you can guarantee Windows support.

On the Mac, you can specify the Apple Symbols font or Menlo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ghoppe!  Does this mean that Gmail's choice of font is the reason for the missing glyph?